# How does React provide independent contexts for subtrees?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

If, as a thought experiment, I were to write my own `createElement` implementation for JSX, what might support for [implicit context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) look like?

In particular, I can't figure out how with the limited means of JSX's `createElement` signature, contexts can be independent for different subtrees. (It appears React's Context handling has become more elaborate in recent versions; I'm mostly interested in the seemingly more straightforward mechanisms of [earlier versions](http://web.archive.org/web/20171225085629/https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#referencing-context-in-stateless-functional-components).)

This might be used to [automatically determine heading levels](https://medium.com/@Heydon/managing-heading-levels-in-design-systems-18be9a746fa3), for example:

```
<Section title="Hello World">
    <Card title="Details" />
</Section>
<Card title="Example" />
```

Here `Card` would automatically generate `<h3>` and `<h2>`, respectively, by relying on something like `context.headingLevel`.

Comment: I really want to answer this but not sure what answer you expect, first, you ask about possible implementation, having metadata like nest level for each component would do the trick. You also ask about how contexts are independent, but it has nothing to do with createElement, think of the idea that you can implement context with HOC, so you basically can inject context values to all sub tree.

Comment: At least older versions of React ([<16.3.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/bbb2ba8c8db747d70f5ef4114051e69aa5950b60/CHANGELOG.md#1630-march-29-2018), apparently) managed to provide `context` to all components, without explicit opt in by component authors - so I'm wondering how they managed that. Surely the answer must lie within the (stateless?) implementation of `createElement`, because that's all JSX allows for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very nice question, that shows how different is the concept of creating React Elements to actually executing the render functions (either the `.render` method of class components or simply the main body of a functional component).

In JSX itself (which is just `React.createElement(…)`) there‘s no concept of “context” at all. It comes into existance only when the components are rendered. It is indeed a duty of the React Renderer (such as React DOM or React Native) to actually implement Context APIs.

If you remove the ability to store states and to update the UI you are left with a minimal React implementation that only “renders once”, but perfectly fine to understand the problem at hand.

Everytime the React Renderer needs to render a React Elements tree (such as one built with JSX) it passes every single element and transforms it into a DOM structure, but when it encounters a component node (not a “native” element) it needs to render it to obtain *its* React Element sub tree, and swap the original node with it.

It’s in this specific moment that React can keep track of which Context values to pass to which components, since it is traversing the tree.

So, to answer directly your question, you can’t implement context in the “element creation phase”, inside your JSX implementation, you need to do it in a subsequent phase when you can traverse the tree.

If you were trying to build an “immediate JSX” you probably have something like this:

```
function createElement(type, props, ...children) {
  props = { children, ...props };

  if (typeof type === 'function') {
    return type(props);
  } else {
    return { type, props };
  }
}
```

In thise case you **will not** be able to implement an API similar to context, because the execution order is inner-then-outer:

```
const div = createElement('div', {}, createElement(Card, {}));
// identical to
const card = createElement(Card, {}); // inner, and then…
const div = createElement('div', {}, card); // outer
```

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I suspected, but your explanation definitely fills in some gaps. I'd still be curious how exactly React's renderer manages to do that context tracking/assignment, but that's probably too complex to explain in this venue. I'll take another look at React's sources either way.

Comment: The best way to understand React internals is to build a React by your self, exactly how you are doing now! Please continue in this journey! If you need a very nice resource, may i point you to this awesome guide: https://pomb.us/build-your-own-react/

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that; it's an impressive guide indeed - though it doesn't seem to address context, so more of general use.